# Duplicating item from one list to another using jquery's sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a normal sortable list, and a "toolbox" from where I want to get elements into the list. So for example:

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
<ul id="toolbox">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

I want to make it so that when you drag one of the toolbox's elements, it creates a copy of itself that can attach to the list. Also, I don't want the user to reorder the elements of the toolbox.

I'm using this, but it doesn't do everything I need:

```
$('#toolbox').sortable({
  'connectWith': '#list',
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[jQuery UI draggable+sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable) is just what you are seeking for.

```
$( "#list" ).sortable({
    revert: true
});
$( "#toolbox li" ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#list",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
});
$( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
```